# Expo app React Native Bluetooth connect With react-native-ble-plx

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth, expo

I have an expo app developped in React Native.
I would like to connect my app to a bluetooth device and I'm using `react-native-ble-plx` but it's not working..
I got the error:  `ERROR  Invariant Violation:` new NativeEventEmitter() `requires a non-null argument.` But I installed the package: `"react-native-ble-plx": "^3.1.2-rc.0",`

There is my code:

```
import {BleManager} from "react-native-ble-plx";
 const manager = new BleManager();

      // Recherche de périphériques Bluetooth
      manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return;
        }

        if (device.name === "apa1") {
          manager.stopDeviceScan();
          device
            .connect()
            .then((device) => {
              console.log("Success");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            });
        }
      });

      return () => {
        manager.destroy();
      };
```

If someone could explain me why it doesn't work.. Thanks in advance guys !

Comment: What do you mean by "an expo app built in react native"?  Are you doing a custom build of the native app using EAS Build?  Or are you trying to develop with the pre-built Expo Go client app?